# How do I secure pro membership features in a Chrome App?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I need to know if an installation has been paid for in the past so I can provide some premium features.

Storing a payment flag in indexeddb or the file system sounds easy to defeat. Periodically asking a server and caching the response could do the trick, but I guess the user would have to be logged-in at all times (through google or otherwise) and I'd rather not impose that restriction.

Maybe if there's a way to uniquely identify a user's machine (uuid, mac address, etc) that could allow me to determine if they've made that payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, this is client side JavaScript.  The only means by which you can prevent use of certain features, is to put them on your server and charge for the service.

Some weak methods for preventing access include license validation, and asking the server for non-essential information (if it was essential, then see the above).

For license validation, you could create an algorithm that takes data from the user and transforms it into something else.  For example, say they create an account on your website, which your server knows is a 'pro' account.  You could then take their first name and email address and do some magic on it.

Here's a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/4rLz9/) that takes those inputs and gives us a key.  In this example if our first name is "John" and our email is "john@domain.org", then our key will be `fcumnflqjpBfqockp0qtifcufLqjp`.  However, Tony, with the email "tony@doman.org" would recieve `fcumnfvqp{Bfqockp0qtifcufVqp{`

You can send this key to the user, and have your code decide whether it can extract the name and email by applying the reverse algorithm.

You can reverse the strings, do various bit math, etc.  It's security by obscurity.  Other than an account, this is the most common method.  It's used by nearly all offline software.  Its kryptonite is key generators, which reverse engineer your code, and generate keys by the algorithm you use to verify them.

Answer (score 0):

All the methods such as uuid, mac address etc can be easily forged imo. I think you cannot escape keeping track of user's logged-in status. Implementing something like a cookie based mechanism would be the right way to go.